# 'then' vs 'and-then' Z3 combinator

Tags: z3

In Z3 `and-then` and `then` and both valid combinators.  What's the difference, if any?  `and-then` gives the following message from `(help-tactic)`:

```
- (and-then <tactic>+) executes the given tactics sequencially.
```

However, `then` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference. If we grep for `"then"` or `"and-then"` in the Z3 source tree, then we find that these strings occur only once and they're synonyms:

```
grep -rE '"and-then"|"then"'
src/cmd_context/tactic_cmds.cpp:        if (cmd_name == "and-then" || cmd_name == "then")
```

Comment: There is no difference, that line of code you cited constructs "and_then"-tactics for both those names. You can ignore "then" to reach consistency with (help-tactic) :)

Comment: Great, that's what I was expecting.